# How to stack same database results based on multiple columns in a Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

In a Laravel project I have a `shapes` table that has the following columns:

`width, height, weight, color_id`

How can I 'stack' all the shapes that are the same with a matching width, height, weight and color?

So far, I've tried to use the `groupBy` method, but when I use multiple criteria, it puts the results in a collection inside of collection inside of collection etc.

```
$stacks = Shape::latest()->get()->groupBy(['width', 'height', 'weight', 'color_id']);
```

My overall goal is to get an array/collection with all available "stacks", and in every stack to have the objects that are matching. Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom group name with `groupBy` so you can combine all the parameters:

```
$stacks = Shape::latest()->get()
     ->groupBy(fn ($item) => $item->width.'-'.$item->height.'-'.$item->weight.'-'.$item->color_id);
```

This should create groups like e.g. `100-200-300-red`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I can customise the  group name like this.